# Dropping Index on 10GB+ InnoDB table takes over 4 hours

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

This is the table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checklist_answer` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `checklistresponse_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `questionoption_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `source` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `award_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `checklist_answer_1f92e550` (`question_id`),
  KEY `checklist_answer_35e0d13d` (`questionoption_id`),
  KEY `answerset` (`checklistresponse_id`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Currently the table has approximately 20 million rows and is about 12GB.  Whenever I attempt to add a new index, or drop an index, it takes a minimum 4 hours.  Is there something glaring that I'm doing wrong or is that just how it is?

MySQL 5.1.49

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL 5.1's built-in InnoDB, then index creation and removal are very slow. This was addressed in 5.5 with [fast indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index.html). Update MySQL if possible. Alternately you can [replace the built in InnoDB from 5.1 with the InnoDB Plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html) (though this should have already been done; given that you're having this issue it probably somehow wasn't).

Answer (score 1):

**Look at the three 36-byte "ID" fields that you are INDEXing.**

I would first suggest reducing those three down to and 8-byte UNSIGNED BIGINT; 4-byte UNSIGNED INT is even better if a 4-Billion number is a big enough.

IF the 4-byte INT "deleted" field is being used as a flag, this could be changed to a 1-byte TINYINT.

You can try issuing:

---

ALTER TABLE `checklist_answer` DISABLE KEYS;

/*

```
 Make you table changes in here.
```

*/

ALTER TABLE `checklist_answer` ENABLE KEYS;

---

Together, I wouldn't be surprised to see the "4 hour" cut in half.

Other Performance-Killers here is:  **"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"**.

Changing this to:  "ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;" could reduce the time in half again.

*BIGINTs are performance killers on 32-bit machines.  64-bit machine will run MariaDB 2.5 times faster than on a 32-bit machine.*